# Instantiate a new instance of GSON for every serialization?

Tags: java, gson

Currently, I have a lot of occurences in my code that read as follows: `result = new Gson().fromJson(someString, ResultContainer.class);` Should I share the GSON object over all those places? If so, per object or static per class (potentially even superclass?)

I am asking mainly because if sharing the reference statically is fine, then why isn't the Gson object static in the first place? Unless one uses fancy custom serialization rules, the method above pretty much covers what one would want Gson to do.

Comment: It's not singleton because you can configure it differently via `GsonBuilder`. See [javadoc](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#Gson()).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [GSON user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Using-Gson):

> The Gson instance does not maintain any state while invoking Json operations. So, you are free to reuse the same object for multiple Json serialization and deserialization operations.

It's not singleton because you can configure it differently via [GsonBuilder](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html).

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the `Gson` is fine.

You can configure a `Gson` using `GsonBuilder` therefore `Gson`is not a singleton.

Comment: it is my experience that it is fine to share, but I can't see anywhere in the doc which says it is so. Can you add a link maybe?

Comment: Ah, found it myself; added my own answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner the Gson team should have definitely put the user guide statement into the Javadoc...

Comment: I must have found an old version of the source, since it does mention thread safety at head: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Gson.java

Comment: @AndyTurner excellent, they corrected this themselves https://github.com/google/gson/commit/0c4ae018361d4756123c82c2f67ad04385caec5b