# Should I instantiate a shared Gson object for all doGet/doPost calls to a Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, gson

Currently I am using the Google's Gson class to parse incoming Ajax JSON strings into Java pojos, as part of the doGet/doPost tasks. I instantiate a new Gson object the usual out from the JSON string the usual way:

```
JsonObj jsonObj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, jsonObj.class);
```

The doubt is if I should instantiate a shared gson object in the servlet initialization to avoid doing `new Gson()` in every servlet doGet/doPost call.

Here [Instantiate a new instance of GSON for every serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968565/instantiate-a-new-instance-of-gson-for-every-serialization) I've learnt that Gson is not a singleton and that some customization is possible with GsonBuilder, but this is not my case.
I am worried about the multithreading behavior of the shared Gson object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: `Gson` is thread safe and you can share it between servlets. See: [Is it OK to use Gson instance as a static field in a model bean (reuse)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380835/is-it-ok-to-use-gson-instance-as-a-static-field-in-a-model-bean-reuse)

But you should decouple `JSON` serialization/deserialization logic from your business logic. For example, in [Spring](https://spring.io/) is done by [*HttpMessageConverter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest) layer. So, first step would be to create shared bean of `Gson` object and second would be creating abstract layer which allow to exchange implementation if it is needed. If you are writing `web-app` anyway, `Spring` is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Micha Zlober.